How can I transform my DOMPurify to purify complex array of object
I have an issue I have a Dompurify function in my angularjs but it doesn't wrk properly when I want to purify complex array of objects
Array of object example :
{
    "Filter": {
        "Services": [
            "aaaaaa"
        ],
        "PriorityID": null,
        "StatusID": "99",
        "CustomerUID": null,
        "Reset": false,
        "UserId": "37989"
    },
    "edit": {
        "PageNumber": "25"
    }
}

This is my function
app.service('DOMPurifyService', function () {
    this.sanitize = function (value) {
        return DOMPurify.sanitize(value)
    }
    this.sanitizeObject = function (obj) {
        let sanitizedObj = {};
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
                    sanitizedObj[key] = this.sanitize(obj[key]);
                } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
                    sanitizedObj[key] = this.sanitizeObject(obj[key]);
                } else {
                    sanitizedObj[key] = obj[key];
                }
            }
        }
        return sanitizedObj;
    };
})

So when I use the function sanitizeObject
This is the result I get
{
    "Filter": {
        "Services": {0: 'aaaaaa'}, < -- here is my problem 
        "PriorityID": null,
        "StatusID": "99",
        "CustomerUID": null,
        "Reset": false,
        "UserId": "37989"
    },
    "edit": {
        "PageNumber": "25"
    }
}

I have this result my problem is why it transform my Array of services into object.
And how can I have an array and not an object for my services.
